# Reinit or update jquery plugin after vue js ajax call

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I have a sidebar and m using jquery vertical carousel plugin(Swiper).

at first the sidebar has a default list and the plugin is working, when i click a link it requests for a diff list for a sidebar and the sidebar_list variable is changed .

now i need to re init or update a plugin because the sidebar is showing both the default list and new list.

In short my requirement is to dynamically change the sidebar list with the carousel working.

Any other ideas or suggestions will be appreciated.
I m using laravel and vue js.

Comment: share live demo/snippet ?

Comment: if the carousel in re-rendered due to data change, the jquery plugin wont work. Because vue uses virtual dom and cannot track changes made by other plugin.

Comment: one solution is to re-init the slider (`new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {})`) everytime there's a data change, using `updated` lifecycle event. But this would be a pretty bad practice. I suggest that you find a vue compatible slider plugin to use instead.

Comment: thanks @JacobGoh for your response.
Can you suggest any other solution for my requirement.?
I want vertically moving siderbar list. 
List must be changing dynamically through Vuejs ajax calls.